# Simple Multiple Desktop restart script that logs and saves output

Tags: powershell, automation

I am starting to learn powershell and all its overwhelming glory and curious how to have a simple  script such as:

```
restart-computer -ComputerName blahblah-mi  -force
```

Which I am asked to make be able to spit out what commands it used, any errors like if a computer wasn't able to be reached and lastly have it save and date the file in a specified path.

I am playing around with `start-Transcript` and Stop but figured may get better response here than keep reading my book and googling.

*also I have tried:

```
restart-computer -ComputerName blahblah-mi  -force > c:\scripts\ranscripts\OUTPUT.txt
```

This ran the command and gave me an output but no date or what command and if any issues essentially just a blank text file named OUTPUT.

#this is for work and has to be done every sunday

Comment: Please provide some current code that you want some help with. Also, consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry first time on here, I updated it.

Comment: No problem. Most of uses needs some guidance in the beginning :)

Comment: You are not suppsoed to redirect the output or restart-computer.
Start-Transcript only stores what commands you've entered, not the results.

It seems that you are trying to write a logfile.

You need to catch errors using the $Error variable or a try{code} catch{handling} structure and then output a corresponding result as text using Out-File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Computer = 'blahblah-mi'
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Computer -Force -ErrorVariable RestartError
if ($RestartError) {
    "$(Get-Date) - Error restarting $computer" | 
    Out-File c:\scripts\ranscripts\OUTPUT.txt -Append
}
else {
    "$(Get-Date) - Successfully restarted $computer" | 
    Out-File c:\scripts\ranscripts\OUTPUT.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: Morning Dennis, wow did not expect so much help. THANK YOU :D. Would you know if there is a limit on computers I can attach to a variable? Maybe a text file with the names? I am struggling to fully grasp powershell due to so different from python and i was beginner with that but could read it and write simple things. So the first line is the variable $Computer that holds the computer the next line is the command with the variable instead of the name with force and im not familiar yet with the -errorvariable restart error apologies. Is there any book or videos you recommend to get better?

Comment: No, just create the variable as a string array, `[string[]]$Computer = @('c1',c2','c3','etc'`). But in that case you need to parse the `$RestartError` variable to find out what computers didn't succeed. Or look into how to work with `foreach-object` or pipes (`|`).